# Internal commutative monoid gives commutative monad

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, semigroups-and-monoids, monoidal-categories, monads

Let $(C,\otimes,1)$ be a [symmetric monoidal category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/symmetric+monoidal+category). Let $(M,\mu,\eta)$ be an [internal commutative monoid object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/commutative+monoid+in+a+symmetric+monoidal+category). 
The functor $X\mapsto M\otimes X$ has a canonical [monad](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monad) structure, with unit and multiplication given by the monoid structure $(\mu,\eta)$.

I would like to see an explicit proof, if it exists, of the following statement:

> The monad described above is [commutative](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+monad).

In particular, I'm looking for a reference on the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly refering to the definition at the nlab, the morphism $\alpha : T(A) \otimes T(B) \to T(A \otimes B)$ is given by the composition
$$\small (A \otimes M) \otimes (B \otimes M) \cong (A \otimes (B \otimes M)) \otimes M \cong ((A \otimes B) \otimes M) \otimes M \cong (A\otimes B) \otimes (M \otimes M) \to (A\otimes B) \otimes M,$$
which is
$$(a \otimes m) \otimes (b \otimes m') \mapsto (a \otimes b) \otimes (m' \cdot m)$$in element notation (see Section 3.3 in [my thesis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.1716.pdf) what element notation roughly means). A similar reasoning shows that the morphism $\beta: T(A) \otimes T(B) \to T(A \otimes B)$ is given by
$$(a \otimes m) \otimes (b \otimes m') \mapsto (a \otimes b) \otimes (m \cdot m').$$ Thus, equality is just the commutativity of the monoid $(M,\mu,\eta)$.

A reference for this is Example 6.3.12 in my thesis, but I am sure that A. Kock already remarked this in one of his papers on commutative monads.

Comment: Which nLab page are you referring to? Thanks!

Comment: The one you linked in your question.

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+monad